# Displaying bad block count without a new HDD rescan

Tags: windows

I know that `chkdsk` will display information aboud bad blocks, but it runs a bit slowly on my  machine. Is there a way to display bad block info without having to run a new scan on the HDD? I know this way I won't find new bad blocks, but there are blocks already marked as bad and I want to know how many there are, without having to run a new scan.

If I run `chkdsk` **without** performing a surface scan, it displays this info:

```
Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.

 193823743 KB total disk space.
  62680076 KB in 219035 files.
    113248 KB in 34374 indexes.
```

> **4 KB in bad sectors.**

```
    416351 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
 130614064 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
  48455935 total allocation units on disk.
  32653516 allocation units available on disk.
```

So the current information about sectors *already* marked as bad is stored somewhere.

I have ran HD Tune but its SMART info doesn't seem to include a bad sectors count.

Comment: So what you're basically asking is that is a status map of all sectors saved somewhere such that full disk access is not required? What if there's an inaccessible sector that's not been remapped/marked as bad yet?

Comment: I don't know if SMART keeps a list, but in that case search for 'read smart statistics ide'.

Comment: This sort of information is not static.  If the S.M.A.R.T data doesn't tell you what you want you have no choice but to scan it again.  The fact it runs slow likely means you have hardware problems with the device itself and it should be replaced.

Answer (score 2):

Run `fsutil volume allocationreport`. (Sample output is below)

Look for the file `$BadClus` with `File ID 0x0008000000000008`

If it is non-zero, you have bad clusters. The file size given for that file in this report will match the number in the CHKDSK output.

```
C:\>fsutil volume allocationreport C:

Allocation report:
Total clusters              : 3907839 (16006508544 bytes)
Free clusters               : 3895093 (15954300928 bytes)
Reserved clusters           : 0 (0 bytes)
Total allocated             : 52207616 bytes

The allocation is split between:
System files                : Count: 27. Total allocated: 52207616 bytes.
    $Mft                    : File ID 0x0001000000000000. Total allocated: 270336 bytes.
    $MftMirr                : File ID 0x0001000000000001. Total allocated: 4096 bytes.
    $LogFile                : File ID 0x0002000000000002. Total allocated: 23691264 bytes.
    $Volume                 : File ID 0x0003000000000003. Total allocated: 0 bytes.
    $AttrDef                : File ID 0x0004000000000004. Total allocated: 4096 bytes.
    Root folder             : File ID 0x0005000000000005. Total allocated: 4096 bytes.
    $Bitmap                 : File ID 0x0006000000000006. Total allocated: 491520 bytes.
    $Boot                   : File ID 0x0007000000000007. Total allocated: 8192 bytes.
    $BadClus                : File ID 0x0008000000000008. Total allocated: 0 bytes.
    $Secure                 : File ID 0x0009000000000009. Total allocated: 274432 bytes.
    $UpCase                 : File ID 0x000a00000000000a. Total allocated: 131072 bytes.
    $Extend                 : File ID 0x000b00000000000b. Total allocated: 0 bytes.
    $ObjId                  : File ID 0x0001000000000019. Total allocated: 0 bytes.
    $Quota                  : File ID 0x0001000000000018. Total allocated: 0 bytes.
    $Reparse                : File ID 0x000100000000001a. Total allocated: 0 bytes.
    $RmMetadata             : File ID 0x000100000000001b. Total allocated: 0 bytes.
    $Repair                 : File ID 0x000100000000001c. Total allocated: 9437184 bytes.
    $Txf                    : File ID 0x000100000000001e. Total allocated: 0 bytes.
    $TxfLog                 : File ID 0x000100000000001d. Total allocated: 0 bytes.
    $Tops                   : File ID 0x000100000000001f. Total allocated: 1048576 bytes.
    $TxfLog.blf             : File ID 0x0001000000000020. Total allocated: 65536 bytes.
    Other system files      : Count: 4. Total allocated: 0 bytes.
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all. On Win 7 it says allocationreport command doesn't exit, on Win 8 and 10 it outputs "Error:  Access is denied."

Comment: @GrayFace On Win7, I presume the command doesn't exist yet. On Win8/Win10, are you sure you are using an elevated command prompt?

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about UAC, got too used to it being disabled on my PC.

Answer (score 1):

In the File Allocation Table (FAT), there is a list of (chained) 32/16/12 bits values that indicate the index of the next allocation unit of a file. 
There is a special value FFFE that indicates that the allocation unit is bad and shouldn't be used for a file or put in the free list.

Hence, when CHKDSK checks that the allocation units are properly chained (index in a file or in the free list), it meets those special values, ignore them but counts them.

That is the count you see.

So, CHKDSK can know the bad allocation units that have already be found without /R requesting a new scan to find possible new ones.